# AngularJS ng-switch without extra DOM

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a custom directive and an object `myObj` on the current `$scope` (inside an `ng-repeat`).

If the object has a `type` of `html`, I want to use one template:

```
<span ng-bind-html="myObj.html"></span>`
```

Otherwise I want to use a different template:

```
<span>{{myObj.value}}</span>`
```

### My problem

This is invalid because a custom directive template must contain exactly one root node:

```
<span ng-if="myObj.type==='html'" ng-bind-html="myObj.html"></span>
<span ng-if="myObj.type!=='html'">{{myObj.value}}</span>
```

This is invalid because it destroys my page with extra DOM: (wrapping all my `spans` (there could be thousands) in unnecessary `ng-switch` nodes...)

```
<ng-switch on="myObj.type">
    <span ng-switch-when="html" ng-bind-html="myObj.html"></span>
    <span ng-switch-default>{{myObj.value}}</span>
</ng-switch>
```

### My Question

Is it possible to have a directive pick it's template based on the result of a switch, without creating extra unnecessary DOM?  For example, you can specify `replace: true` when creating a directive - is it possible to similarly have an `ng-switch` where the result replaces the switch tag itself?

### Edit

My Directive:

```
return {
    replace: true,
    controller: 'ChunkController',
    scope: {
        chunk: '=deChunk'
    },
    templateUrl: de.partial.chunk,
    link: function (scope, el, attr, ctrl) {
        el.on('keydown', handleKeypress.bind(ctrl));
        el.on('click', ctrl.showValue);
    }
};
```

And its usage:

```
<div class="content" contenteditable="{{node.type!=='static'}}">
    <div data-ng-repeat="chunk in node.chunks" data-de-chunk="chunk"></div>
</div>
```

With the intent that the child `<div>` will be *replaced* with the sequence of `<span>s` from above.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't even bother if you are storing the html in a service just check to see if a value for myObj.html exists in the object and if it does compile and bind the html in the linker function instead of using ng-bind-html

something like this maybe:

```
myapp.directive('something',function($compile){
      return {
        link: function(scope,elem,attrs) {
          var obj = scope.$eval(attrs.something);
          if(obj.html) {
            var html = angular.element($compile(obj.html)(scope));
            elem.append(html);
          } else {
            //go get the data and set obj.html 
          }
        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: Unfortunately this replaces the `<ng-switch>` with the `<div ng-repeat="chunk in node.chunks">` because it doesn't perform the replace (see edit)